# How to submit the form with out reloading the page in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am developing a program using codeigniter.
my view file having a form

```
<form id="form" name="enquiry">
    <ul>
       <li>
           <label>Name</label>
           <input name="name" type="text" id="name" class="required"/>
       </li>
       <li>
           <label>Email</label>
           <input name="email" type="email" id="email" class="required"/>
       </li>
       <li>
           <label>Telephone</label>
           <input name="telephone" type="text" id="telephone" class="required"/>
       </li>
       <li>
           <button type="submit" id="enquiry_submit">Send</button>
       </li>
   </ul>
</form>
```

for this i am using jquery for submitting and validation

```
$("#form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var name1 = $('#name').val();
        var email1 = $('#email').val();
        var telephone1 = $('#telephone').val();
        if(name1 && email1 && telephone1) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '<?= base_url()?>'+'frontend/form_enquiry',
                data: 'name='+name1+'&email='+email1+'&telephone='+telephone1
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Here frontend is my controller to store the data.I am using this form as a popup for all pages. Its working fine in home page but not worked in other pages. When submit the form the page should be loaded. I want without loading the page i need submit the form.

Comment: And there is no similar case in http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=103&tab=relevance&q=submit%20without%20reload ?

Comment: should work what is the issue?

Comment: I want without  loading the file i need to submit the form. its worked in my home page but not in other

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 <button type="submit" id="enquiry_submit">Send</button>
```

to

```
 <button type="button" id="enquiry_submit">Send</button>
```

for more read this http://w3code.in/2015/09/how-to-insert-and-view-data-without-refreshing-page-using-ajax-and-jquery-in-codeigniter/

Comment: In view do the change I have told you and in ajax do the code provided by @Krupesh Kotecha

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#form").validate({
     submitHandler: function(form) {
         var name1 = $('#name').val();
         var email1 = $('#email').val();
         var telephone1 = $('#telephone').val();
         if(name1 && email1 && telephone1) {
             $.ajax({
             type: 'post',
             url: '<?= base_url()?>'+'frontend/form_enquiry',
             data: 'name='+name1+'&email='+email1+'&telephone='+telephone1
         },
        success: function(msg)
        {
            alert('test message');
        }               
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#form").validate({
             submitHandler: function(form) {
                var name1 = $('#name').val();
                var email1 = $('#email').val();
                var telephone1 = $('#telephone').val();
                    if(name1 && email1 && telephone1) 
                    {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'post',
                            url: '<?= base_url()?>'+'frontend/form_enquiry',
                            data: 'name='+name1+'&email='+email1+'&telephone='+telephone1
                        });
                        return false
                    }
                }

            });
})
```